# Unable to write data into a file using python

Tags: python, linux, file

```
outfile = open(inputfile, 'w')
outfile.write(argument)
outfile.flush()
os.fsync(outfile)
outfile.close
```

This is the code snippet. I am trying to write something into a file in python. but when we open the file, nothing is written into it. Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Why are you flushing `stdout`, and not closing the file object?

Comment: Sorry. It was a mistake

Comment: And why did you name the outputfile inputfile?

Comment: Is it a script, or you are trying in python shell? If it is a script, the file should be closed automatically on exit, so that shouldn't be the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not calling the `outfile.close` method.

No need to flush here, just call close properly:

```
outfile = open(inputfile, 'w')
outfile.write(argument)
outfile.close()
```

or better still, use the file object as a context manager:

```
with open(inputfile, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(argument)
```

This is all presuming that `argument` is not an empty string, and that you are looking at the right file. If you are using a relative path in `inputfile` what absolute path is used depends on your current working directory and you could be looking at the wrong file to see if something has been written to it.

Comment: Shouldn't the file be closed (and flushed) automatically on script exit ?

Comment: @SunnyNanda: Yes, the file would also be closed when Python exits. There is no mention of that in the question though. I also mention that the presumption is that `argument` is not an empty string.

Comment: @SunnyNanda: Added another assumption; that the OP is looking at the right file.

Comment: Thank you Martjin Pieters. Your second option worked!!

Comment: @user2599593: Then the first one would have worked too; all `file.__exit__()` does is call `self.close()`. `file.__exit__()` is called when the `with` block ends.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
outfile.close()
```

note the brackets.

```
outfile.close
```

would only return the function-object  and not really do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You wont see the data you have written into it until you flush or close the file. And in your case, you are not flushing/closing the file properly.

```
* flush the file and not stdout - So you should invoke it as outfile.flush()
* close is a function. So you should invoke it as outfile.close()
```

So the correct snippet would be

```
  outfile = open(inputfile, 'w')
  outfile.write(argument)
  outfile.flush()
  outfile.close()
```